# Declaring and using custom-class vectors

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

My mate and I have just come accross a problem we couldn't manage to solve just yet.

We have two classes, `solution` and `generation`.

`solution` has a lot of attributes, and `generation` has, among others, a `vector<solution> pool` attribute.

The generation class has a `generatePool` function :

```
void generation::generatePool(int initsize){
  for(int i = 0; i < initsize; i++){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    pool.push_back(get_randomized_solution(args));
  }
}
```

in which `get_randomized_solution` itself returns a solution. Problem is, the program compiles but crashes (Segmentation fault) at the `push_back`line

We've already tried `resize` and `reserve` on the `pool` vector, we also tried using pointers... but it still crashes and now google (and SO) seemingly have gone out of ideas to help us. We've also redefined `solution& solution::operator=(const solution&)` and a `solution::solution()` (with no arguments) constructor, which basically returns an empty `solution`. Where do you think the problem comes from ?

EDIT:

Here's the `get_randomized_solution` method:

```
solution get_randomized_solution(int size, int rcap, int rcom, bool randomized){
  solution sol = solution(size, rcap, rcom);

  vector< pair<int,int> > cibles;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = (i==0) ? 1 : 0; j < size; j++){
      cibles.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
    }
  }

  srand(rand());
  if(randomized) random_shuffle(cibles.begin(), cibles.end());

  for(int k = 0; k < cibles.size(); k++){
    if(sol.removeCaptor(cibles[k])){
      if(!sol.realisable()){
        sol.addCaptor(cibles[k]);
      }
    }
  }
  return sol;
}
```

More complete code: https://codeshare.io/2jLnzB

Comment: Do the `solution` class follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: [mcve] please. The likely culprit is `get_randomized_solution`. Notice it's missing.

Comment: We also implemented the copy constructor `solution::solution(const solution &s)`, didn't change anything

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes it does.

Comment: *How* do you implement copy-construction? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't call `srand` more than *once*. And don't use `rand` to provide the seed. Unless you want the random numbers to be *predicable* and not very random of course. Also note that the overload of [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) you use is deprecated since the C++14 standard and removed in the C++17 standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller I really thought my question was well posed... I edited the post.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do `attribute = s.attribute` on all attributes of the `solution` class

Comment: It's still not a [minimal, ***complete***, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what *are* those "attributes"? I assume you mean member variables? Are any of them pointers? Just doing assignment is no different than the default copy-constructor which in many cases is not enough. Do you do *any* deep copying?

Comment: @Yocto - It's still not well posed. Please read the [mcve] page carefully. Understand what it means with regard to your example. Then reduce the clutter until it's a good code sample. You may even find the problem on your own that way. Another useful reference is the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) description.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed I meant member variables. Not any of them are pointers, these are only vectors, vectors of vectors (int, pair<int,int> and bool), and integers.

Comment: Here's a snippet with all you need (tell me if it's not enough) : https://codeshare.io/2jLnzB

Answer (score 0):

Well that was indeed get_random_solution, in which there was a `size = size` line which caused the bug. Really sorry for useless posting.